# FBX vertex count mystery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a skinned character model that's imported from an FBX file. In play mode the stats show that this model has 13.5k vertices. With the script below attached the stats say the model uses only 4.4k vertices.

The script adds a SkinnedMeshRenderer to the model's gameobject and then copies all the relevant mesh data over from the original SkinnedMeshRenderer (gameobject child) to the newly added one.

The original model has several materials that are all the same (except hair), and the copy simply uses one material (looks fine, except for the hair of course).

Can anyone explain why the copy has a much lower vertex count than the original?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CopyMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // original

        SkinnedMeshRenderer originalSkin = transform.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        Mesh originalMesh = originalSkin.sharedMesh;

        // copy

        SkinnedMeshRenderer copySkin = transform.gameObject.AddComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        Mesh copyMesh = new Mesh();

        // set up copy's SkinnedMeshRenderer

        copySkin.sharedMesh = copyMesh;
        copySkin.material = originalSkin.materials[0];
        copySkin.bones = originalSkin.bones;
        copySkin.rootBone = originalSkin.rootBone;

        // copy over required vertex data

        copyMesh.bindposes = originalMesh.bindposes;
        copyMesh.vertices = originalMesh.vertices;
        copyMesh.normals = originalMesh.normals;
        copyMesh.uv = originalMesh.uv;
        copyMesh.boneWeights = originalMesh.boneWeights;
        copyMesh.triangles = originalMesh.triangles;

        // disable original SkinnedMeshRenderer so that only the copy shows up

        originalSkin.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be happy about it then ^^

Comment: You may have some settings to merge identical vertices. So the system looks for vertices that have the exact same position and makes them one then reorganize the index array and uv mapping.

Comment: You are using `GetComponentInChildren()`, may your model have more than 1 Mesh? Try using `GetComponentsInChildren()`, and use a while to process all Meshes

Comment: @Windgate - No, there's only one mesh.

Comment: Your material/shader may be rendering multiple passes.

Comment: @Leo Bartkus - No, that's really not the case. Just checked.